# Spring Boot: Get an object from MongoDB document?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot 2.1.3.RELEASE and MongoDB. And I am looking for a way to retrieve a part of a document.

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface CompanyRepository extends MongoRepository<Company, String> {
}
```

Object:

```
@Data
@Document
public class Company {

  public GeneralInfo info;
  public Map<String, List<Employee>> officeIdEmployeeMap;

  @Data
  public class GeneralInfo {
    @Id
    public String companyId;
    public String name;
  }

  @Data
  public class Employee {
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
  }
}
```

I need to get only `GeneralInfo` objects and then if some conditions are true get the `List<Employee>` from the `officeIdEmployeeMap`, not the whole map.
Can this be done by MongoRepository?

Comment: Do you mean in mongo shell you get the same result by doing this: `db.comany.find({}, { generalInfo: 1}`? If yes you can add a custom query corresponding to that in the repository.

Comment: No, I did't mean in mongo shell. I was trying to get in my app. Tnx anyway

Comment: I know you are trying to get this in the app. The clarification I need is how do you do this if you use mongo shell. Is it something like: `db.comany.find({}, { generalInfo: 1}`?

Comment: Sorry. Yes, that would by the shell query.

Answer (score 0):

In `CompanyRepository` add the following method:

```
@Query(value="{}", fields = "{'info':1}")
public List<Company> getCompanies();
```

Call this when you need to get only General Info otherwise, call `findAll()` to get all details. You may write a new Query in the repository restricting the selected fields and optionally the criteria.

In case you want to achieve both the scenarios (get GeneralInfo only and get both) in the same query conditionally, instead of annotation create a query like below:

```
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

Query query = new Query();
boolean someCondition = true; // Put your condition here
if(someCondition) {
    query.fields().exclude("officeIdEmployeeMap");
}
return mongoTemplate.find(query, Company.class);
```

Assuming your company data in the database looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d3afb75b2ebf8a9ec2f906f"), "info" : { "companyId" : "1", "name" : "abc" }, "officeIdEmployeeMap" : { "g1" : [ { "firstName" : "A", "lastName" : "B" }, { "firstName" : "C", "lastName" : "D" } ] } }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is possible with MongoTemplate.

```
finalString officeName = "IT";
final Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("officeIdEmployeeMap." + officeName).exists(true));
query.fields().exclude("officeIdEmployeeMap");

final Company company = mongoTemplate.findOne(query, Company.class, "collection");
```

This will return the `Company` object but only `GeneralInfo` will be set.